# can't get total value of product items into the total text element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

1. I have list of product item which generated dynamically.
2. I calculated each item total using *calculateItemTotal()* method.
3. what I wanted to do is take the sum of all these item totals in to the **total** text field.
4. but, instead of summing item totals, total text field only shows the last item total price.
5. If anyone can give me insight , How to figure this out would be great.

---

### Total text element

### ```html
<label class="control-label col-xs-5">Total: </label>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <input type="text" name="totalprice" id="finaltotalprice" class="form-control">
</div>
```

### Dynamically added rows

- **rowId** is already defined in the script...no problem with the rowId.
- **onchange()** functions are working correctly as well.

```html
<td>
  <input type='text' name='quantity[]' class='form-control' id='quantity_"+ rowId +"' value='"+ orderItems[list].sales_list_item_quantity +"' onchange='calculateItemTotal("+ rowId +")' >
</td>"
<td>
  <input type='text' name='discount[]' class='form-control'  id='discount_"+ rowId +"' onchange='calculateItemTotal("+ rowId +")' >
</td>
<td>
<!-- this is where the item total price is set and working correctly  -->
  <input type='text' name='itemtotalprice[]' class='form-control' id='itemtot_"+ rowId +"' >
</td>
```

---

### This is my *calculateItemTotal()* function

```js
function calculateItemTotal(data) {
  let quantity = parseInt($("#quantity_"+data).val()); // take the quantity value to quantity variable -- ok
  
  if(isNaN(quantity)) quantity = 0; // make it 0 if it is not a number
  
  let unitPrice = parseFloat($("#unitprice_"+data).val()); // take the unit price value to the unit price variable --ok
  
  if(isNaN(unitPrice)) unitPrice = 0.00;
  
  let tot = quantity * unitPrice; // calculation is ok
  
  let discount = (parseFloat($("#discount_"+data).val())/100 * tot).toFixed(2); // calculation is ok
  
  if(isNaN(discount)) discount = 0.00;
  
  let net_total = tot - discount; // this is also ok
  
  let with2Decimals = net_total.toString().match(/^-?\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?/)[0]; // this is also ok
  
  $("#itemtot_"+data).val(with2Decimals); // set the calculated price of product item -- ok

   // something is wrong here!
   let finalTot = 0;
   finalTot += $("#itemtot_"+data).val();
   $("#finaltotalprice").val(finalTot);
}
```

---

### Here is the image of what I'm getting

[image: total is should be 1780]

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following line:

```
finalTot += $("#itemtot_"+data).val();
```

[val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function returns a string. To be able to do arithmetic functions on the returned value, you need to convert it to integer using [parseInt()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) function.

Comment: thank you for the comment. I did with your suggestion, but first time around it perfectly adding the each item price to the total price. but , when I changed the quantity Total value is giving me incorrect value.